# When does this second order PDE imply a first order PDE?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

While trying to solve a geometric question, I came to the following problem:

Let $q(r,\theta)$ be a smooth positive function, and suppose that
$$
\frac{q_{rr}}{q}
$$
depends only on $r$.
Is it true that
$$
s=\frac{q_r}{q}
$$depends only on $r$?

I am quite certain that the answer can be negative, but I am struggling to find an example. Also, are there some further natural conditions on $q$ which imply that $\frac{q_r}{q}$ depends only on $r$?

---

Differentiating, we have
$$
s_r+s^2=\frac{q_{rr}}{q}=F(r).
$$

Does this imply that $s_{\theta}=0$?

Differentiating again, this leads to
$$
s_{r\theta}+2ss_{\theta}=0.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counterexample, take $F(r)=1+r^2$. The PDE
$$s_r+s^2=1+r^2$$
has the general solution
$$s(r,\theta)=r+\frac{e^{-r^2}}{c(\theta)+\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2} \text{erf}(r)}. $$

In general, given that $\frac{q_{rr}}{q}$ is a function of $r$ alone we have
$$s=\frac{q_r}{q}\text{ is radial} \Longleftrightarrow (\log q )_{rr} \text{ is radial}.$$

Suppose $$(\log q)_{rr}=\varphi(r).$$
Integrate twice to get
$$\log q=\Phi(r)+A_1(\theta) r +A_0(\theta),$$
for $\Phi(r)$ of class $C^2$. Hence
$$q(r,\theta)=\mathrm{e}^{\Phi(r)+A_1(\theta) r +A_0(\theta)}.$$